# Separate function showing error

Tags: r

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
NEI_baltimore$year.type<-paste(NEI_baltimore$year,NEI_baltimore$type,sep = ".")
baltimore_sums<-aggregate(NEI_baltimore$Emissions,by=NEI_baltimore["year.type"],FUN=sum)
separate(data = baltimore_sums,col = year.type,into=c("year","type"),sep = ".")
```

I have used the following code to split the column that I have pasted for getting the aggregate function in that pasted column.

I am getting the warning and no value are showing in the splitted column

```
Warning message:
Too many values at 16 locations: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16
```

Comment: Please format your code properly. It is unreadable. read the help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify `sep = "."` when it comes to `separate` and using `.`. Just omit that argument and see if it happens again.

Comment: Can you add some of your code using `dput()` to show us the structure?